# Which one is the better usage of "how long does it take"?

Tags: grammar

I saw two different usages of this structure :

> how long does this semester take us to be completed?

> how long does it take us to complete this semester?

Which one is better?

Comment: I think “how long does it take for us to complete this semester?” is right.

Comment: The first one is simply wrong, because it needs to be "the semester takes to be completed" or "it takes us to complete the semester", but never "the semester takes us to be completed".  This deserves a longer explanation of why, but I don't have time right now.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer in you two examples is:

> how long does it take us to complete this semester?

Since you are probably asking how long until the semester is finished.
It would be better worded as:

> how long **will** it take **for** us to complete this semester?

since the semester ends some time in the future.

The phrasing of the first sentence, seems to be asking:

> how long **will** this semester take **for** us to be completed?

Meaning you are correctly incomplete, but after the semester ends you will be considered "complete".
It is a possible way of asking this question, but is still awkward.